# How can detect Codeigniter url for matched route?

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I'm using codeigniter for develop my website. I want to find matched route for every url. For example, my url is `example.com/edit-user/1/test` and my route is

```
$route['edit-user/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'user/edit/$1/$2';
```

Now, when `example.com/edit-user/1/test` is requested, I need to get
`edit-user` only, without `1/test`.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

welcome controller

```
public function edit_user()
{
    $this->load->view('edit-user');
}
```

routes

```
$route['edit-user'] = 'welcome/edit_user';



 your url
<a href="<?php echo base_url('edit-user'); ?>">Edit User</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).